# Get a span using the span ID in Open Telemetry

Tags: java

Is there any way in Open telemetry to get a span when you have the span ID? I am using Java and
I want to set the parent  , but I receive only the spanID of the parent in my method , so I wonder if there is a way to get the parent span.

```
   Span span = tracer.spanBuilder(name)
                .setParent(Context.current().with(parentspan))
                .startSpan();
```

I didn't find any method that allows you to get the span based on the span ID.

Answer (score 0):

Opentelemetry supports span propogation from a remote span. the caller can use OtelPropogator Inject to create a traceId string and the callee can use OtelPropogator extract.

example from Opentelemetry: [Context Propogation](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/manual/#context-propagation)